# Accessing Database for MVC4 default project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Entity framework with .NET MVC 4, so I have a Models folder with all the models I will be using I.E.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class TestDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime SubmittedDate { get; set; }
        public int userID { get; set;}

    }
}
```

its working like its supposed to, whenever I write or read to the database, but what I cannot find is the actual database where all this is being stored. Some articiles say its supposed to be in the App_Data folder, but there is nothing there. Other articles online mention it being a database in the local SQLEXPRESS, but I I cannot connect to it when I try to go to Data Connections -> add new Connection -> Microsoft SQL Server, there is nothing there.

**My connection string:**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-BeatBaz-20140209122055;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

but it isnt showing in the server explorer, what is common practice when testing and debugging to look at the data that is getting saved?

[image]

Comment: what is on your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to View -> Server Explorer -> Data Connections. You are suppose to see your data base there.
You don't need to add new connection.

In the top of your web.config is section called connectionsStrings. What does that say?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the web.config in the root of your project (not the one in the views folder) and see what's in the connectionStrings section. That will be where your data lives

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viewing all files in the solution explorer?  I know when I first created a project it didn't show up, even with refreshing, until I clicked on the view all or show all files which than brought up the .mdf file.   You than should be able to double click on the .mdf file to bring it up in the server explorer.

Comment: nope I think because its not us the local mdf file but accessing one sqlexpress

Answer (score 0):

Yah, look at the connection string at web.cofig..
Or click "Show All Files" button in your solution explorer.. 
And you don't need to add a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

you can find using

- in the Server Explorer itself you will find on top "Connect to
  Database" (a database with + symbol).
- then select the Data Source you mentioned with the connection string.
- Follow the steps accordingly through the wizard and you can find the
  Database displayed in the Server Explorer.